# Make batch FOR /F ignore Registry AutoRun

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently decided to up my cmd game a little and found that I could register macros and do other fun stuff using the AutoRun registry key (`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`).

Because I was getting tired of constantly having to look up my SSH key for git or to do `start-ssh-agent` I now want to run it immediately on cmd startup thus (so the plan at least) prompting me for my ssh key password once and then have it connect to the running ssh-agent on each subsequent commandline I open.

I ran into an issue however! `start-ssh-agent` (provided by git for windows) makes use of `FOR /F` in order to gather information about a potentially running ssh-agent by running `tasklist /FI "Imagename eq ssh-agent.exe"`. From [Windows Server Docs on For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) (emphasis mine):

> You can use the for /f command to parse the output of a command by placing a back-quoted  between the parentheses. It is treated as a command line, which is **passed to a child Cmd.exe**. The output is captured into memory and parsed as if it is a file.

That child cmd.exe is not passed `/D` however so in order to evaluate the tasklist command, a new cmd is opened, that runs start-ssh-agent that wants to evaluate the tasklist command so it creates a new cmd; you see where this is going.

**A lot said so here goes the question:** Is there any way for me to address this issue and not run into an endless creation of new commandlines by either disabling use of AutoRun for whatever is run in `for /f` or any other measure?

Comment: wrong approach: don't start *every*  instance of `cmd` with your desired toolset. Instead create a destop icon to start a batch file which does your modifications (for this instance only).

Comment: Unfortunately, `for /F` uses `cmd /C` to start sub-commands, in contrast to pipes (`|`), which use `cmd /S /D /C` for either side, and `/D` disables such auto-start things…

Comment: Thousands of applications including `cmd.exe` and the Windows shell run `cmd.exe` in background. The command line registered with registry value `AutoRun` is executed always by `cmd.exe` on starting it independent on which process runs `cmd.exe` for which reason. Therefore you used the completely wrong approach. I recommend like Stephan to create a shortcut file (.lnk file) to open a command prompt window and execute a command line or a batch file to setup the environment you would like to have on working manually with Windows command prompt.

Comment: My answer on [How to change directory with BAT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135726/3074564) explains in detail how to start `cmd.exe` with running a batch file to setup a specific environment and keep running for manual execution of commands. Run in an opened command prompt window also `cmd /?` and read in output help how a command line after option `/C` or `/K` is interpreted by Windows Command processor. It is perhaps possible to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /K` with just a command line instead of an entire batch file with the shortcut to setup the wanted environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan), [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) and [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) as well as a coworker of mine, I changed approaches and switched to [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) as my preferred terminal which has convenient setups for environments which allows running start-ssh-agent on startup as hoped.

I moved all my doskey "aliases" to `cmder\config\user_aliases.cmd` and uncommented the line `call "%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%/cmd/start-ssh-agent.cmd" /k exit` in `cmder\config\user_profile.cmd`.